# Can you insert a form onto a page using jQuery's $.load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, innerhtml

I have a page where there's a drag and drop table where the order of the rows determines the value of a subtotal. However, it's more complicated than just addition and I would rather not duplicate the logic in JavaScript to update the values.

A simple solution would be to reload the whole page using Ajax and then replace the table from the page fetched via Ajax. Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution but I thought it'd be a quick way to get the job done that would be acceptable for now.

You can do that with jQuery like this:

```
$('#element-around-table').load(document.location.href + ' #table-id');
```

However, my "simple" solution turned out to not be so simple because the table also contains a `<form>` tag which is not being displayed in Firefox (Safari works).

When I inspect the page using Firebug, I see the form, but it and its elements grayed out.

Searching on the web, I found a [rather confused post](http://www.jqueryhelp.com/viewtopic.php?t=935&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=&sid=3bbfd58b10cde4db6961f2c2fdf6f062) by a guy who says FF3 and IE strip `<form>` tags from `innerHTML` calls.

I'm probably going to move on to do this some other way, but for my future reference, I'd like to know: is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

That post is rather confused, I just tested your code and it worked fine.  The form tag was shown in firefox 3.0.8 just fine.

Looking at you code example, though I wonder if you just gave an incomplete example... make sure that the page you call returns **only** the html that goes inside that wrapper element.

Comment: I may try the approach of only returning the HTML I need -- it'd be faster -- but isn't that what the second part of the call to $.load() is for? It's a selector for the HTML returned that you can use to only insert a piece of the page returned. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Comment: It only inserts a piece of the page, but you still have to fetch the whole thing and then filter it down with code.

Comment: you only showed one parameter... and the other parameters are data to send to the server (form post) nd a callback function to call on the data.  No, the url you give to load needs to return only the section you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this type of thing before. FORM tags need to be added to the DOM. If they're added using a method that writes to innerHTML, the tag will appear, but it won't be there as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Comment: I'm kind of a JavaScript newb. How do you add the tags to the DOM?